# R: Compare each value with set of previous values in column

Tags: r, dplyr

### Question

Say we have a dataset like this one:

```
df <- data.frame(X = c(1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4))
```

How do I compare every value with a set of previous values, ideally in `dplyr`?

### Specific example

For every value, I want to know if it is bigger than every single one of the 4 previous values, (excluding cases where there aren't 4 previous values), with the desired output of:

```
> df
   X  Diff
1  1    NA
2  2    NA
3  3    NA
4  4    NA
5  5  TRUE
6  4 FALSE
7  3 FALSE
8  2 FALSE
9  1 FALSE
10 2 FALSE
11 3 FALSE
12 4  TRUE
```

### Tried so far

I can achieve a basic comparison with the previous value only, using the `diff` function:

```
df$diff <- c(NA, ifelse(diff(df$X) > 0, "TRUE", "FALSE"))
> df
   X  Diff
1  1  <NA>
2  2  TRUE
3  3  TRUE
4  4  TRUE
5  5  TRUE
6  4 FALSE
7  3 FALSE
8  2 FALSE
9  1 FALSE
10 2  TRUE
11 3  TRUE
12 4  TRUE
```

I have looked into the `rollmax()` function in the `zoo` package, but could not find a way to restrict the comparison to only the previous 4 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rollapply` but need to adjust the window size based on expected output. If you want to check for previous 4 values, set the window size to be 5 and then check if the last value is higher than all the previous ones.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
k <- 5

df %>% mutate(Diff = rollapplyr(X, k, function(x) all(x[k] > x[-k]), fill = NA))


#   X  Diff
#1  1    NA
#2  2    NA
#3  3    NA
#4  4    NA
#5  5  TRUE
#6  4 FALSE
#7  3 FALSE
#8  2 FALSE
#9  1 FALSE
#10 2 FALSE
#11 3 FALSE
#12 4  TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(zoo)

df <- data.frame(X = c(1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4))
df %>%
  mutate(diff = X > lag(rollmaxr(X, 4, fill = NA)))

   X  diff
1  1    NA
2  2    NA
3  3    NA
4  4    NA
5  5  TRUE
6  4 FALSE
7  3 FALSE
8  2 FALSE
9  1 FALSE
10 2 FALSE
11 3 FALSE
12 4  TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

Another `dplyr` and `zoo` option could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(Diff = X > rollapply(X, 
                             width = list(c(-4:-1)), 
                             FUN = max, 
                             fill = NA)

  X  Diff
1  1    NA
2  2    NA
3  3    NA
4  4    NA
5  5  TRUE
6  4 FALSE
7  3 FALSE
8  2 FALSE
9  1 FALSE
10 2 FALSE
11 3 FALSE
12 4  TRUE
```